# Need a little help on where to put the conversions for the textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating an inventory system and have everything lined up, I just need help converting textboxes to the proper variable type. This is only a portion of the project, I just need one example to go by.

//saves part
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (apMinBox > apMaxBox)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Minimum cannot be greater than the Maximum.");
                return;
            }

```
        if (addPartIHRadio.Checked)
        {
            Inhouse inHouse = new Inhouse((Inventory.Parts.Count + 1), apNameBox, apInvBox, apPpuBox, apMinBox, apMaxBox, int.Parse(apMachineBox));
            Inventory.AddPart(inHouse);
        }
        else
        {
            Outsourced outsourced = new Outsourced((Inventory.Parts.Count + 1), apNameBox, apInvBox, apPpuBox, apMinBox, apMaxBox, apMachineBox);
            Inventory.AddPart(outsourced);
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes add part form
        mainFormObject.Show();
        Close();    
    }
```

Comment: "convert textboxes to proper type"? What exactly do you mean here? What is your input-data, what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: so basically it's supposed to take the textbox values and add the new part to an inventory class. the error i get is "cannot convert system.windows.form.textbox' to 'string', 'int', 'decimal', etc.

Comment: Is this WPF? Then use data-binding. Or can your textbox´ value have different data-types?

Answer (score 0):

If targeting the current .NET Framework e.g. 4.7 or higher then consider asserting the two TextBox controls have valid types e.g.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(apMinBoxTexBox.Text, out var minBoxResult) && int.TryParse(apMinBoxTexBox.Text, out var maxBoxResult))
            {
                if (maxBoxResult > minBoxResult)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Minimum cannot be greater than the Maximum.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // in range
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While the above works you could create events e.g. KeyPress to disallow unwanted values such as no "." or letters etc for a int TextBox or create custom TextBox controls that only accept the type you want.

Then there is Data Annotations which works in Window forms project also.

See also http://www.reza-aghaei.com/dataannotations-validation-attributes-in-windows-forms/

Comment: where is this specific to 4.7?

Comment: it is WPF. Really i just need to bind the text in the boxes to their appropriate variable in the base class

Comment: @HimBromBeere the var for out clause in the TryParse rather than use out.

Comment: @JimmLee - I don't see this as WPF as with WPF the click event parameters are Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

Comment: `var out` is a **language-feature**, not **runtime**, whch exists since C#6, which exists since from VS2015 upwards. You could use that feature even with .NET 3.5 (not sure if lower works also, as the distinction between language- and runtime isn´t that strict).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the textboxes to other type, you could refer to [Convert Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.8).

The following is a code example that convert textboxes(string type) to int type.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(txtMin.Text);
        int max = Convert.ToInt32(txtMax.Text);
        if (min > max)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Minimum cannot be greater than the Maximum.");
            return;
        }

        if (addPartIHRadio.Checked)
        {
            Inhouse inHouse = new Inhouse((Inventory.Parts.Count + 1), apNameBox, apInvBox, apPpuBox, apMinBox, apMaxBox, int.Parse(apMachineBox));
            Inventory.AddPart(inHouse);
        }
        else
        {
            Outsourced outsourced = new Outsourced((Inventory.Parts.Count + 1), apNameBox, apInvBox, apPpuBox, apMinBox, apMaxBox, apMachineBox);
            Inventory.AddPart(outsourced);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```